# problem with comparing a name from getter method to user input string

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-operator, getter

i'm having trouble comparing in my if statement, in C programming i am using "==" double equal sign to compare two string...

how about comparing a string using getter method to a new string... i try to use the double equal sign but i was prompted to change it into this:

if (entry[i].getName().equals(EName))

by the way this is my whole code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class AddressBook {

    private AddressBookEntry entry[];
    private int counter;
    private String EName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AddressBook a = new AddressBook();
        a.entry = new AddressBookEntry[100];
        int option = 0;
        while (option != 5) {
            String content = "Choose an Option\n\n"
                    + "[1] Add an Entry\n"
                    + "[2] Delete an Entry\n"
                    + "[3] Update an Entry\n"
                    + "[4] View all Entries\n"
                    + "[5] View Specific Entry\n"
                    + "[6] Exit";
            option = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(content));
            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    a.addEntry();
                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
                case 3:
                    a.editMenu();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    a.viewAll();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.exit(1);
                    break;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Choice!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void addEntry() {
        entry[counter] = new AddressBookEntry();
        entry[counter].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name: "));
        entry[counter].setAdd(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter add: "));
        entry[counter].setPhoneNo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Phone No.: "));
        entry[counter].setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter E-mail: "));
        counter++;
    }

    public void viewAll() {
        String addText= "";
        for (int i = 0; i <  counter; i++) {
            addText = addText+(i+1)+ entry[i].getInfo()+ "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(addText));
    }

    public void editMenu() {
        int option = 0;
        while (option != 6) {
            String content = "Choose an Option\n\n"
                    + "[1] Edit Name\n"
                    + "[2] Edit Address\n"
                    + "[3] Edit Phone No.\n"
                    + "[4] Edit E-mail address\n"
                    + "[5] Back to Main Menu";
            option = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(content));
            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    editName();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    editAdd();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    editPhoneNo();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    editEmail();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    return;
                default:
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Choice!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void editName() {
        EName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to edit: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (entry[i].getName().equals(EName)) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "found");
                entry[i].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new name: "));
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered Name not Found!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void editAdd() {
        EName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to edit: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (entry[i].getName().equals(EName)) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "found");
                entry[i].setAdd(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new Address: "));
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered Name not Found!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void editPhoneNo() {
        EName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to edit: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (entry[i].getName().equals(EName)) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "found");
                entry[i].setPhoneNo(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new Phone No.: "));
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered Name not Found!");
            }
        }
    }

    public void editEmail() {
        EName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name to edit: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            if (entry[i].getName().equals(EName)) {
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "found");
                entry[i].setEmail(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter new E-mail add: "));
            }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entered Name not Found!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my other class:

```
public class AddressBookEntry {

    private String name;
    private String add;
    private String phoneNo;
    private String email;
    private int entry;

    public String getAdd() {
        return add;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setAdd(String add) {
        this.add = add;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setEntry(int entry) {
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getInfo() {
        String Info = "NAME\tADDRESS\tPHONE NO.\tE-MAIL ADD\n"
                + name + "\t " + add + "\t " + phoneNo + "\t " + email + "\n";
        return Info;
    }

    public String getInfo2() {
        String content = "INFORMATION:\n\n"
                + "Name: " + name + "\n"
                + "Address: " + add + "\n"
                + "Tel. No: " + phoneNo + "\n"
                + "Email Add: " + email + "\n\n";
        return content;
    }
}
```

PLEASE PARDON MY CODE... i am new at java.... please help....

what i want to is traverse to all the array and edit the specific detail if the user input was equals to the entry[i].getName()

thanks a lot in advance...

Comment: Do not use `==` to compare strings in C. Bad things will happen.

Comment: So what's the actual question here?

Comment: Are you really using `==` to compare strings in "C"?  As nmichaels commented, that's not going to give the expected results because it compares the address of the two strings in memory, and not the content of the strings themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `equals()` if you want to compare the representation of the string and not its object identity.

Assume we have: `String s = "hello";`

```
s == s
=> true // they are the *same* object
"hello" == new String("hello") // see comment below...
=> false // they are different objects representing the same string of text
"hello".equals("hello")
=> true
s.equals("hello")
=> true
```

Comment: in fact, `"hello" == "hello"` **is true**, too (since identical compile-time constant strings are the same String object).

Comment: thnx Jeremy... since i am comparing two strings... .equals is better to use thanks

Comment: Now we have to hope that this `sayHello()` method does something else then `return "Hello"` :-p   `"hel".concat("lo")` is (almost) surely a different String object, and `new String("hello")` surely is.

Comment: @Paŭlo: Yeah... I was assuming that :-P Just tested both of your examples, and you are correct once again!

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 things to understand:

Java: == tests whether two references point to the same object, whereas equals tests whether two objects have the same content. So, even if two Strings have the same content, == may give false whereas s1.equals(s2) will give true. You can find loads about this on google.

C: In C, you shouldn't compare two strings using == either. Strings in C generally are char* (or const char*), and you should compare them with strcmp (or else you will run into the same problems as in Java).

C++: instances of std::string can be compared using ==.